# How to update Django model fields after filtering by id?

Tags: python, django, get

I want to write a function that, when executing a `"GET"` request, will change fields such as: `"inaction"` and `"lastAction"` to `2` and the `datetime.now()`. But when I wrote my code for the first time, I encountered an error: `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object`.

This code:

```
def update(self, res_id: str):
        user, updated = User.objects.filter(id=res_id).update(inaction="2", lastAction=datetime.now())
        code_status = HTTPStatus.ACCEPTED if updated else HTTPStatus.OK.value
        return user, code_status
```

For this reason, I rewrote my code to the following and that started works:

```
def update(self, res_id: str):
        updated_rows = User.objects.filter(id=res_id).update(inaction="2", lastAction=datetime.now())
        user = User.objects.filter(id=res_id).first()
        code_status = HTTPStatus.ACCEPTED if updated_rows else HTTPStatus.OK.value
        return user, code_status
```

But in this code, I'm worried about duplicates of the form: `User.objects.filter(id=res_id)`. How can I avoid them?

models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    operatorId = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    operator = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    inaction = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    lastAction = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'
        db_table = "users"
        ordering = ('-createdAt',)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return UsersEntity.to_string(self)
```

entities.py

```
class UsersEntity:
    id: int
    operatorId: str = None
    createdAt: date = None
    operator: str = None
    inaction: int = 1

    @staticmethod
    def to_string(user: 'UsersEntity') -> str:
        operatorId = f"({user.operatorId}):" if user.operatorId else ValueError
        return f'{user.id} -> {operatorId}'
```

Comment: Did you customize the manager of the user model?

Comment: **@willeM_VanOnsem**, Yes, I did it

Comment: can you share the custom manager you defined?

Comment: yes, of course, the main thing is to understand what is the matter)

Answer (score 0):

To optimize your Django code and avoid duplicating the `User.objects.filter(id=res_id)` query, you should utilize Django's querysets and transactions effectively.

You can do this:

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.utils import timezone

def update(self, res_id: str):
    with transaction.atomic():
        # Lock the rows for update and get the user instance
        user = User.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=res_id).first()

        # Check if the user exists
        if not user:
            code_status = HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND.value
            return None, code_status

        # Update the fields
        user.inaction = 2
        user.lastAction = timezone.now()
        user.save(update_fields=['inaction', 'lastAction'])

        code_status = HTTPStatus.ACCEPTED.value
        return user, code_status
```

By using `transaction.atomic()` in this Django code, I make sure all the database changes stick together. It's an all-or-nothing approach. I also lock the rows I'm working on with `select_for_update()` to avoid any mix-ups if two updates happen at the same time. Before updating, I check if the user actually exists to avoid unnecessary steps. Once I find the user, I update their 'inaction' and 'lastAction' right on the spot, which is simpler. Plus, I use `django.utils.timezone.now()` for correct time handling. In the end, I return the user info with an appropriate code, like saying 'user not found' if they aren't there.

[You can check this as a reference for select_for_update() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update)